# ejabberd clustering running db []

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, mnesia

I follow this step ejabberd offical document for clustering.After entering this command in running ejabberd directory

```
root@slave:/home/xxx/Desktop/ejabberd-2.1.13/src# erl -sname ejabberd \ -mnesia dir '"/var/lib/ejabberd/"' \ -mnesia extra_db_nodes "['ejabberd@master.192.168.1.44']" \ -s mnesia
then mnesia:info()
```

its shows terminal like this
`===> System info in version {mnesia_not_loaded,nonode@nohost,{1387,355144,32779}}, debug level = none ==opt_disc.Directory "/home/hari/Desktop/ejabberd-2.1.13/src/Mnesia.nonode@nohost" is NOT used.use fallback at restart = false
running db nodes   = []
stopped db nodes   = [nonode@nohost] 
ok`

Comment: can anyone suggest me correct ejabberd clustering setup steps or website i spent one week for ejabberd clustering in all the material s are same nothing special for this topic can any give the clustering steps for ejabberd server

Comment: You are not providing enough detail in your questions. Please provide more details on what you've done, more detail on what happens, and improve the formatting of your error messages.

Comment: sir give me your mail id i will send the details

Answer (score 0):

Since [ejabberd 15.03](https://blog.process-one.net/ejabberd-15-03/), ejabberd clustering has been considerably simplified, with a simple "join_cluster" command. There is no need anymore to type manual Mnesia commands.

It is explained on ejabberd Documentation site: [ejabberd clustering](http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/clustering/)